# Swift3 - Cells with image is not displayed

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im trying to set the background view as an image but it never displays the cells with images. I can scroll down so I know that there are indeed cells there but there are no background images, whenever i scroll really fast you can kind of make out the correct image but it vanishes quickly.

Any ideas why?

heres my code:

```
let image: UIImageView = {
    let imgview = UIImageView()
    imgview.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
    imgview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imgview.clipsToBounds = true
    return imgview
}()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell-id", for: indexPath)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(image)
    cell.backgroundView = image
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `addSubview` method in `cellForItemAt`. Because `cellForItemAt` is called many many times.

Try this code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell-id", for: indexPath)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.frame.size)
    UIImage(named: "myImage")?.draw(in: cell.bounds)
    if let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This code worked for me too! I am now using it for cells in a UITableView. Thank you.